# Rails forms processing as HTML mistakenly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The following form of a Rails 6 application

```
<%= form_with(model: @cartitem, local: false) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

renders in HTML the following:

```
<form action="/cartitems" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token">
</form>
```

However upon submission of the form, the action is logged as an HTML response:

```
Started POST "/cartitems" for ::1 at 2022-02-07 20:52:37 +0100
Processing by CartitemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "cartitem"=>{"price_ordered"=>"14.9", "article_id"=>"9269", "fulfilled"=>"false", "q_order"=>"3"}, "button"=>""}
```

which is thoroughly unexpected... and contrary to the behaviour of the application of few days ago.  The only idea of a change that may have impacted is that of addressing content Security Policies - but I fail to see where that could impact rails logic, when `local: false` and the HTML rendered `data-remote="true"`.

The defualt Rails CSPs were amended as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
   policy.default_src :self, :https
   policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
   policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
   policy.object_src  :none
   policy.style_src   :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
   policy.connect_src :self, 'https://api.stripe.com'
   policy.frame_src   :self, 'https://js.stripe.com', 'https://hooks.stripe.com'
   policy.script_src  :self, :https, :unsafe_inline, 'https://js.stripe.com'
 end
```

Where should one investigate? What is going on here?

Rails 6.1.3 and Ruby 2.6.1

**Update**
also attempted with `form_for`  which renders from

```
<%= form_for(@cartitem, url: cartitems_path, method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

the following

```
<form action="/cartitems" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

and still gets logged as:

```
Started POST "/cartitems" for ::1 at 2022-02-08 18:04:33 +0100
Processing by CartitemsController#create as HTML
```

Scrupulously, the controller has:

```
class CartitemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cartitem, only: %i[ show edit edit_q update update_q update_shop substitute destroy ]
[...]
  def create
    @cartitem = Cartitem.new
    authorize @cartitem
    if !@cart.accepted?
      @cartitem = Cartitem.create(article_id: @article.id, quantity_ordered: @quantity_ordered, price_um: @price_um, vat: @vat, price_ordered: @price_ordered, cart_id: @cart.id)
      @destroy = false
    end
  end
```

*end_update*

Comment: question amended

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? Did you check if Rails UJS is working otherwise - like for example links with data-method?

Comment: Yes.  the console warns `POST http://localhost:3000/cartitems 406 (Not Acceptable)` essentially Rails is dead set on handling via HTML.  Rails UJS *is* working in other instances (example `<%= form_with(url: select_departmentsub_articles_path, method: :post, local: false) do |f| %>`

Comment: @max  sorry, I did leave on warning out: `Failed to set referrer policy: The value 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged.` under localhost.  But how could that impact Rails' handling of the request mistakenly?

Comment: @Jerome Did you ever figure this out ?  Seeing similar behavior.

Comment: honest answer: 'dunno'. Admittedly, I have not diligently tracked the various attempts, driven by new applications generation & migrating to rails 7.  On occasion things run. why? dunno. Between this & CSP, the combo definitely has some 'dark' elements about it, around which I have yet to properly wrap my head or arms around.  The only lamp that lights is with the use of the `data` attribute within the tag; I would focus on the proper use of that..

Comment: @Jerome it seems this behavior has to do with the deprecation of js.erb in Rails 7.  I am going to learn the new technique.  https://twitter.com/dhh/status/1252751363219419136?s=20&t=1k08JKslQu_G_Y6dOVdviQ

Comment: any good documentation on this is welcome.  have you tried with the `data` attirbute tag?

Comment: @Jerome do you mean data: { turbo: false }, if so yes I have that in there and still get the same issue, processing as HTML and ActionController::UnknownFormat.